# Re-asking for declined facebook permissions

Tags: facebook, fbsdk, fbjs, fbloginview

What would be the proper way of re-asking user permissions? I am specifically interested in `pages_show_list`. There FB gives the user a list of pages to select from. Assuming the user would not have selected all of them at first run, i might want to show the list once again at some point of application lifecycle. How would i do that?

I found calling

```
FB.login(statusChangeCallback, {scope: 'pages_show_list', return_scopes: true})
```

would not do the trick as it would simple confirm the user has already linked fb to app as `You've previously linked [AppName] to Facebook`. There is a way to go Edit and then modify a list, but unlikely user would understand to do that.

A second option i came across is to revoke the permission first

```
FB.api('/me/permissions/pages_show_list', 'DELETE', function(){
   FB.login(statusChangeCallback, {scope: 'pages_show_list', return_scopes: true})
});
```

but then, what would happen to the pages i have check at first run? I assume they would be revoked and access tokens would become obsolete.

Comment: Does `pages_show_list` even get you any page access tokens? I’m not sure what exactly you fear becoming “obsolete” here.

Comment: It does not give me a tokens right away, but rather a set of pages i have given right to use. Which means, if i uncheck one or two, tokens would loose its power. Which is entirely the same if i show the list every time.. hmm so, thats probably less of a problem for becoming obsolete, but still correct workflow is important question.